# Identifying Machine/User ID Perl

Tags: perl, server, system, admin

There is a web site that has banned a client of mine. If he signs up for an account at this site with computer 'A' his account is immediately cancelled. If he signs up for an account with computer 'B' there's not a problem. (the site is unable to identify him)
I would like to be able to do this with my site. (ie: identify a user by his computer) I can identify environmental variables but this doesn't seem to be what this site is using. 
I'm not sure how to even tag this question. Any help is appreciated.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<pre>\n";

foreach my $key (sort keys(%ENV)) {
print "$key = $ENV{$key}<p>";
}
print "</pre>\n";
```

Comment: There are a number of ways you can track machines from HTTP requests: remote IP and cookies being the most common. You can't see the requester's environment, only what they send and where they send it from.

Comment: I think this is too broad; there are various ways of identifying users (cookies, email address, credit card number). You can even go as far as blocking whole IP addresses or ranges, like Wikipedia sometimes does. It will depend on how much effort you want to spend and how bad false classifications are.

Comment: We've deleted all relevant cookies for this site. So they aren't relying on cookies. I was hoping to be able to identify machine ID, Serial Number,  Hardware UUID or similar. Guess not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you correctly, that your client is using computers A and B inside the same network so that the requests come from the same IP, correct?

On the server side - this is what you are doing - you can only identify a user by their IP address. Everything else (cookies, user agent information, language preferences, ...) is sent on a voluntary basis and unreliable.

Repeat your experiment with JavaScript disabled and the remote side will probably fail to identify the user. With JavaScript you can collect an astonshing amout of information about the user's hard- and software: OS, plug-ins installed, fonts installed, screen resolution, properties of the graphics hardware (by painting to a canvas and analyzing the result), properties of the audio hardware, and lots of other stuff. See https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2 for an impression of what is possible.

You can then send all that information in an AJAX request back to the server and react upon it. But this approach is also inherently limited:

1. The user may disable JavaScript (although you can avoid that by requiring JavaScript for the registration process).
2. The user may manipulate the information sent.
3. The user may block AJAX calls or this particular AJAX call.

But practice shows that this approach is quite successful.